# Python: how to import csv file from github into text file

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have the following webpage on GitHub whereby I would like to import its content into python particularly jupyter notebook

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://github.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/blob/master/groceries.csv'
file1=open(url,'r')
UnOrgan=file1.read()
```

But it did not work

```
SError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a URL to open(). Try using the requests library:

```
import requests

url = 'https://github.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/blob/master/groceries.csv'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: It did not exactly work as expected? I only want the file not everything in the page

Comment: Use the raw file URL instead: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/groceries.csv`

Answer (score 2):

Enter the webpage that you are trying to import and click [Raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kreqL.png) as shown below.
[image: Click Raw]

Copy the address from your browser: 
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/groceries.csv"

```
#Use the address here:
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/groceries.csv'
#Name the resulting dataframe
dataDF = pd.read_csv(url)
```